# context-sensitive generation using quick check

Tags: haskell, quickcheck

I would like to generate random terms based on some sort of "context" and I was wondering if this is possible using quickcheck. Basically I would like to have an additional data type passed around so that the arbitrary function can generate terms based on the additional parameter... Is this possible with quickcheck or should I just write my own definition of Gen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible, though not really sane, to do this from within `arbitrary`. But if you step out of `arbitrary`, you can *literally* just pass an extra parameter around.

```
-- do whatever you want inside the implementation of these two
chooseIntRange :: Context -> Int
updateContext :: Int -> Context -> Context

arbitraryIntWithContext :: Context -> Gen (Context, Int)
arbitraryIntWithContext ctx = do
    n <- choose (0, chooseIntRange ctx)
    return (n, updateContext n ctx)
```

The plumbing of the context can be relieved somewhat with `StateT`, e.g.

```
-- do whatever you want inside the implementation of this
chooseIntRangeAndUpdate :: MonadState Context m => m Int

arbitraryIntStateT :: StateT Context Gen Int
arbitraryIntStateT = do
    hi <- chooseIntRangeAndUpdate
    lift (choose (0, hi))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I can see how I can change this to use polymorphic types and create a ContextArbitrary typeclass out of this

Answer (score 1):

While Daniel Wagner has supplied a fine answer for QuickCheck (+1), it also highlights one of QuickCheck's weaknesses. In QuickCheck, one writes properties using instances of `Arbitrary`, but due to its design, `Arbitrary` isn't monadic.

The workaround that Daniel Wagner shares is that `Gen`, on the other hand, *is* monadic, so that you can write context-dependent code using `do` notation. The disadvantage is that while you can convert a `Gen a` to an `Arbitrary a`, you'll either have to provide a custom `shrink` implementation, or forgo shrinking.

An alternative library for property-based testing, [Hedgehog](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/hedgehog), is designed in such a way that properties themselves are monadic, which means you'd be able to write an entire property and simply embed ad-hoc context-specific value generation (including shrinking) in the test code itself:

```
propWithContext :: Property
propWithContext = property $ do
  ctx <- forAll genContext
  n <- forAll $ Gen.integral $ Range.linear 0 $ chooseIntRange ctx
  let ctx' = updateContext n ctx

  -- Exercise SUT and verify result here...
```

Here, `genContext` is a custom generator for the `Context` type, with the type

```
genContext :: MonadGen m => m Context
```